# Who brought balance to the force?

Tags: star-wars

In *Star Wars* Qui-Gon Jinn mentions a prophecy about a chosen one to bring balance to the force, which he supposes to apply to Anakin Skywalker.

But was it really **Anakin Skywalker** or **Luke Skywalker**? What I feel is that Anakin as **Darth Vader** disturbed the **force**, whereas Luke changed him at the end. Therefore I think Luke brought balance to the force. Was **Qui Gon** mistaken? Or is it implicitly pointing to Luke?

Comment: Kindly eloborate little more what you want to know.

Comment: who brought balance to force.I think its luke as i mentioned above.I just wanted to know how anakin brought balance to force

Comment: You can view this in different ways. I would still say, Anakin brought balance. He almost singlehandedly destroyed the Jedi order, so they were down to the "same" number of Jedi and Sith: Obi Wan and Yoda vs. Palpatin and Anakin. I am no Star Wars expert, but there were probably some other Jedi living in exile. But still the distribution is matched better than a few hundred Jedi vs. 2 Sith

Comment: Anakin did bring balance. He brought Luke to life.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Star Wars canon points to Anakin Skywalker being the one who brings balance to the Force. Please follow this link [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23906/how-was-the-chosen-one-meant-to-bring-balance-to-the-force) to see expanded discussion on what the prophecy actually means regarding balance to the Force, and whether or not it was even fulfilled.

George Lucas, in the commentary of A New Hope stated:

> Which brings us up to the films 4, 5, and 6, in which Anakin's offspring redeem him and allow him to fulfill the prophecy where he brings balance to the Force by doing away with the Sith and getting rid of evil in the universe...

This proves that "balance" does not necessarily mean equal number on both sides. The answer in the link also states:

> ...the prophecy probably means that Anakin would bring harmony between the two sides of the Force, which requires the destruction of the Sith whose aim was to destroy the Light side.

The user admits during his conclusion that there isn't even total agreement on whether the prophecy was actually fulfilled. [The answer to this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/how-did-darth-sidious-manage-to-diminish-all-of-the-jedis-ability-to-use-the-fo/22772#22772) gives great insight and evidence as to how the Sith unbalanced the Force in the first place, creating the need for it to be balanced.